# Performing a count of each level of a factor grouping by another factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like a dataframe output where the  count 2 of 4 levels ("Yes" and "No") of a variable are recorded. I can do it by subsetting and filtering on yes or no but I feel there must be a better way to do this with dplyr

```
null.ta <- dbdata %>%
filter(MutGroup == "Null") %>%
group_by(ICD_Grouping) %>%
summarise(n()) %>%
spread(???????)
```

Above is what I assume I have to do to an extent but do not know how to get the spread function to work for this particular variable. I don't mind if all 4 levels are included then I can just cut a couple columns after the fact.

```
structure(list(ICD_Grouping = structure(c(50L, 50L, 33L, 33L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 18L, 21L, 33L, 18L, 18L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 16L, 17L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 16L, 16L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 16L, 18L, 
17L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 21L, 30L, 21L, 18L, 21L, 21L, 
13L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 13L, 34L, 33L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 18L, 10L, 34L, 37L, 34L, 34L, 18L, 33L, 33L, 18L, 18L, 37L, 
50L, 30L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 34L, 34L, 33L, 17L, 
14L, 19L, 33L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 34L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 30L, 30L, 17L, 17L, 33L), .Label = c("", "C01-2", "C03-6", 
"C09-10", "C11", "C15", "C16", "C18-20", "C21", "C22", "C25", 
"C30-31", "C33-34", "C37-39", "C40-41", "C43", "C44", "C45", 
"C47/49", "C48", "C50", "C51", "C53", "C54-55", "C56", "C57-58", 
"C60", "C61", "C62", "C64", "C65-66/68", "C67", "C69", "C70", 
"C71", "C72", "C73", "C74-75", "C76.0", "C76.2", "C76.3", "C80", 
"C81", "C82-86", "C90.0", "C91.0", "C94.3/95", "D04", "D05", 
"D22", "D31", "D33", "D35"), class = "factor"), Immunohistochemistry = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("", "N/A", "No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-115L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I would like an output that would look like

```
ICD_Grouping Yes No N/A
C22           2   1   0
C45           7   3   1
C69           4   0   0
```

That is an example of random data, not this data. Would just like a data frame with the counts of each factor level in Immunohistochemistry by ICD_Grouping.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your data (use `dput` and paste the output into the question) and desired output

Comment: @divibisan Sorry - Have included extra information now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, we can just do that with base `table`:

```
table(dbdata)
```

`table` will show results for each level (even if it's no longer present in the data), so to make the table reasonably sized, we use `droplevels` to remove unused levels first:

```
table(droplevels(dbdata))

            Immunohistochemistry
ICD_Grouping N/A No Yes
      C22      0  0   1
      C33-34   0  0   2
      C37-39   1  0   0
      C43      0  2   7
      C44      1  2   8
      C45      2  0  17
      C47/49   1  0   0
      C50      0  1   4
      C64      0  0  10
      C69      7  0   2
      C70      1  0   6
      C73      0  1   1
      D22      8  0  30
```

A `table` can be converted to a data.frame with the same structure using:

```
table(droplevels(dbdata)) %>%
    as.data.frame.matrix() %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column('ICD_Grouping')
```

or if you like pipes:

```
dbdata %>%
    droplevels() %>%
    table() %>%
    as.data.frame.matrix() %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column('ICD_Grouping')
```

Both give the same `data.frame` as a result:

```
   ICD_Grouping N/A No Yes
1           C22   0  0   1
2        C33-34   0  0   2
3        C37-39   1  0   0
4           C43   0  2   7
5           C44   1  2   8
6           C45   2  0  17
7        C47/49   1  0   0
8           C50   0  1   4
9           C64   0  0  10
10          C69   7  0   2
11          C70   1  0   6
12          C73   0  1   1
13          D22   8  0  30
```

This form is a proper data frame that can be used in any downstream processes, or joined on the `ICD_Grouping` variable

Comment: I have worked it that way before but I was remiss to add that I need the ICD_Grouping as a definitive column that I will use for a left_join with other tables. I have multiple tables that left join on ICD_Grouping. That is why I was trying to use the dplyr package as the tibble output works perfectly for the left joins.

Comment: @SebWalpole You can easily convert the output of `table` into a format that works in a dplyr chain